# Merging Data to Run Specific Individual Analysis

Tags: loops, merge, analysis, stata

I have two data sets. `FIRST` is a list of products and their daily prices from a supplier and `SECOND` is a list of start and end dates (as well as other important data for analysis). How can I tell Stata to pull the price at the beginning date and then the price at the end date from `FIRST` into `SECOND` for the given dates. Please note, if there is no exact matching date I would like it to grab the last date available. For example, if `SECOND` has the date 1/1/2013 and `FIRST` has prices on ... 12/30/2012, 12/31/2012, 1/2/2013, ... it would grab the 12/31/2012 price.

I would usually do this with Excel, but I have millions of observations, and it is not feasible.

I have put an example of `FIRST` and `SECOND` as well as what the optimal solution would give as an output `POST_SECOND`

```
FIRST
 Product          Price              Date
   1               3                1/1/2010
   1               3                1/3/2010
   1               4                1/4/2010
   1               2                1/8/2010
   2               1                1/1/2010
   2               5                2/5/2010
   3               7                12/26/2009
   3               2                1/1/2010
   3               6                4/3/2010

SECOND
Product          Start Date          End Date
   1              1/3/2010            1/4/2010
   2              1/1/2010            1/1/2010
   3              12/26/2009          4/3/2010

POST_SECOND
 Product         Start Date          End Date      Price_Start     Price_End
   1              1/3/2010            1/4/2010          3             4
   2              1/1/2010            1/1/2010          1             1
   3              12/26/2009          4/3/2010          7             6
```

Comment: @SOConnell Merging the data into one and making indicator variables but that is getting very messy and not working well

Answer (score 1):

Here's a merge/keep/sort/collapse* solution that relies on using the *last* date. I altered your example data slightly.

```
/* Make Fake Data & Convert Dates to Date Format */
clear
input byte Product         byte Price            str12  str_date
   1               3                "1/1/2010"
   1               3                "1/3/2010"
   1               4                "1/4/2010"
   1               2                "1/8/2010"
   2               1                "1/1/2010"
   2               5                "2/5/2010"
   3               7                "12/26/2009"
   3               7                "12/28/2009"
   3               2                "1/1/2010"
   3               6                "4/3/2010"
   4               8                "12/30/2012"
   4               9                "12/31/2012"
   4               10               "1/2/2013"  
   4               10               "1/3/2013"  
 end

gen Date = date(str_date,"MDY")
format Date %td
drop str_date    
save "First.dta", replace

clear 
input byte Product          str12 str_Start_Date        str12  str_End_Date
   1              "1/3/2010"            "1/4/2010"
   2              "1/1/2010"            "1/1/2010"
   3              "12/27/2009"          "4/3/2010"
   4              "1/1/2013"            "1/2/2013"
end

gen Start_Date = date(str_Start_Date,"MDY")
gen End_Date = date(str_End_Date,"MDY")
format Start_Date End_Date %td
drop str_*
save "Second.dta", replace

/* Data Transformation */
use "First.dta", clear
merge m:1 Product using "Second.dta", nogen

bys Product: egen ads = min(abs(Start_Date-Date))
bys Product: egen ade = min(abs(End_Date - Date))
keep if (ads==abs(Date - Start_Date) & Date <= Start_Date) | (ade==abs(Date - End_Date) & Date <= End_Date)
sort Product Date
collapse (first) Price_Start = Price (last) Price_End = Price, by(Product Start_Date End_Date)
list, clean noobs
```

---

*Some people are reshapers. Others are collapsers. Often both can get the job done, but I think collapse is easier in this case.

Comment: This works well, but what if, as in the last part of the question if, "Please note, if there is no exact matching date I would like it to grab the last date available. For example, if `SECOND` has the date 1/1/2013 and `FIRST` has prices on ... 12/30/2012, 12/31/2012, 1/2/2013, ... it would grab the 12/31/2012 price." When I change `Product 3's Start_Date` to `12/27/2009` your solution does not work.

Comment: I spaced about that part. Take a look at my updated solution. Does it do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

In Stata, I've never been able to get something like this to work nicely in one step (something you can do in SAS via a SQL call). In any case, I think you'd be better off creating an intermediate file from `FIRST.dta` and then merging that 2x on each of your `StartDate` and `EndDate` variables in `SECOND.dta`.

Say you have data for price adjustments from Jan 1, 2010 to Dec 31, 2013 (specified with varied intervals as you have shown above). I assume all the date variables are already in `date format` in `FIRST.dta` & `SECOND.dta`, and that variable names in `SECOND` do not have spaces in them.

```
tempfile prod prices

use FIRST.dta, clear
keep Product
duplicates drop
save `prod'

clear
set obs 1096
g Date=date("12-31-2009","MDY")+_n
format date %td
cross using `prod'

merge 1:1 Product Date using FIRST.dta, assert(1 3) nogen
gsort +Product +Date /*this ensures the data are sorted properly for the next step  */
replace price=price[_n-1] if price==. & Product==Product[_n-1]
save `prices'

use SECOND.dta, clear
foreach i in Start End {
rename `i'Date Date
merge 1:1 Product Date using `prices', assert(2 3) keep(3) nogen
rename Price Price_`i'
rename Date `i'Date 
}
```

This should work if I understand your data structures correctly, and it should address the issue being discussed in the comments to @Dimitriy's answer. I'm open to critiques on how to make this nicer as its something I've had to do a few times and this is how I usually go about it.